# ServerClick not working on IP Address using Internet Explorer

Tags: asp.net

My superior asked me to redirect or always use an IP based address for the web application that I created.

> Ex: Instead of using http://www.google.com, the project should use
>   http:/ /173.194.127.46

In this way, the computers on our network could visit the webportal directly.

Unfortunately, when I use the IP, the server script on code behind doesn't work. I tried to create a simple one to prove it right.

**Default.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnClick" Text="Test Click" />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" />
        <button runat="server" id="btnClick2">Test Click 2</button>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

**Default.aspx.vb**

```
Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub btnClick_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClick.Click
        Label1.Text = "Clicked from ASP Button"
    End Sub

    Protected Sub btnClick2_ServerClick(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClick2.ServerClick
        Label1.Text = "Clicked from HTML Button"
    End Sub

End Class
```

The code on HTML Button does not work, like it doesn't have a script.

**There are html tags I placed inside the HTML Button so replacing to ASP Button will not solve it.**

Is there a way I can make the codes on HTML Button work?

---

**Update**: It is working on the latest version of Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox

Comment: Try to set AutoEventWireup=true.

Comment: It doesn't work either

Comment: If you do by http://localhost and it is working and if you do http://ipaddress then it is not working then it has IE security issue. Which browser you are using ?

Comment: I don't see where you're using the IP Address.

Comment: @dotnetstep: Currently, I am using IE11, but I need to support lower versions of IE, such as IE6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it but I need further testing!

Here's what I've done.

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="true" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">.hid{display: none;}</style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" name="form" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnClick" Text="Test Click" />
        <button runat="server" id="btnClick2">Test Click 2</button>
        <button runat="server" id="btnClick3" onclick="document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].btnHidden.click();return false;">Test Click 3</button>
        <asp:Button runat="server" CssClass="hid" ID="btnHidden" />
        <br /><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" />
    </div>
    </form>
    <script type="text/VB" runat="server">
        Protected Sub btnClick_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClick.Click
            Label1.Text = "Clicked from ASP Button"
        End Sub

        Protected Sub btnClick2_ServerClick(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClick2.ServerClick
            Label1.Text = "Clicked from HTML Button"
        End Sub

        Protected Sub btnHidden_Click(s As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnHidden.Click
            Label1.Text = "Clicked from ASP Button via HTML Button"
        End Sub

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

What I did is add ASP Button that will trigger the server script. Then on the HTML button, I added **onclick** event that will perform a click on ASP Button.